# c++ вывести таблицу заполнив значениями с клавиатуры

Tags: c++, массивы

[image: дали еще такие алгоритмы,я писала не по ним]
[image: я не очень их поняла,но может пригодятся]
задание:Составить программу, в которой будут вводиться 7 - 10 строк таблицы, образец которой приведен в Вашем варианте индивидуального задания к лабораторной работе и выводится на экран таблица - сразу же после ввода и после сортировки ее по значениям в первом столбце.[image: вот пример результата:]

**под таблицей должно выводить что-то вроде отсортированного одномерного массива(как я поняла сортировать нужно те числа,которые вводятся в таблицу**
вот мой код

```
using namespace std;
bool mycomp(string a, string b) {
    return a < b;
}
vector <string> alphabaticallySort(vector<string>a) {
    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), mycomp);
    return a;
}
main(void) {
 
    int size;

    cout << "vvedit kilkist radkiv: \t";
    cin >> size;
    struct {
        string name;

        string type;

        int sq;

        float crc;

    } tabN[size];
    vector<string>names;
    for (int i = 0; i < size;i++) {
        cout << "\n" << i + 1 << ".vvedit: nazvy, type, ploschy, vrojainist:";
        cin >> tabN[i].name >> tabN[i].type >> tabN[i].sq >> tabN[i].crc;
        names.push_back(tabN[i].name);
    }
    names = alphabaticallySort(names);
    struct {
        string name[15];

        string type;

        int sq;

        float crc;

    }
    newtabN[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < size;j++) {
            if ((tabN[i].name == names[j])) {
                newtabN[j].type = tabN[i].type;
                newtabN[j].sq = tabN[i].sq;
                newtabN[j].crc = tabN[i].crc;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "|----------------------------------------------------------|\n";
    cout << "|              silskogospodarski kulturi                   |\n";
    cout << "|----------------------------------------------------------|\n";
    cout << "|                                                          |\n";
    cout << "|   nazva   |   type   |   ploscha   |    vrojainist       |\n";
    cout << "|----------------------------------------------------------|\n";
    for (int j = 0;j < size;j++) {
        stack<int> names;
        stack<int> type;
        stack<int> sq;
        stack<int> crc;
        names.push(11);
        type.push(9);
        cout << "|" << names.top() << "|" << type.top() << "|\t\t  "<<setprecision(4)<<
        sq.top() << "|" << fixed << setprecision(2)<< crc.top() << "|\n";
        names.pop(); type.pop();sq.pop();crc.pop();
     }
    cout << "|--------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
    cout << "|primitka: Z-zernovi          B-bobovi                         |\n";
```

код не работает, поэтому прошу совета)

Comment: Что конкретно значит "не работает"?

Comment: ввод с клавиатуры предлагает, но таблицу не выводит(только шапку)

Comment: А где вы выводите таблицу? У вас там вывод из каких-то частично *незаполненных* стеков. В них вы ничего не вводите, вообще-то...

Comment: если честно плохо понимаю как их правильно заполнить, уже 2 недели мучаю лабу эту(